# Dynamic browser resolution for Protractor testing

Tags: testing, configuration, protractor

my question concerns end to end testing scenario involving a responsive web app. I have written my test scenario for the pages to test with different test cases depending on the screen resolution. I am using array variables to store the different selectors linked to the same element, for example:

```
  it('should display the log in page', function () {
    gVar.signInButton = element(by.css(gVar.signInButtonSelector[gVar.SelectedMode]));
    gVar.signInButton.click().then(function(){
      expect(element(by.css(gVar.titleLoginPageSelector[gVar.SelectedMode])).getText()).toEqual(gVar.titleLoginPage[i]);
    });
```

Here I am trying to select the login page title to test it. Depending on the resolution, only the selector is different, and I stored them in arrays...

In my conf.js I have a parameter variable that I use in the command line to set the configuration I want to use:

```
    exports.config = {
    //...

      params:{
            resolutionConfig:'default'
            },  

    //...
    }
```

the run command can go:

`protractor conf.js --params.resolutionConfig=Classic` or

`protractor conf.js --params.resolutionConfig=Mobile` or

`protractor conf.js --params.resolutionConfig=Tablet` ...

(Then I have a matching table to associate this parameter to the above integer value: gVar.SelectedMode)

What I would like to do now, is to set different resolutions values for my browser, a different one for each value of resolutionConfig parameter I am testing. So far, I know how to set that resolution with hardcoded values:

```
    exports.config = {
    //...

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--window-size=100,100'] // THIS!
        }

    //...
    }
```

I have heard of "multicapabilities" to run parallel tests, but it is not exactly what I want… is it possible to have the resolution parameters in variable and add a logic to it? Something like:

```
    if(resolutionConfig) is "mobile" then: ['--window-size=xx,xx']; 
    if(resolutionConfig) is "tablet" then: ['--window-size=yy,yy'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your initial question you can use `browser.driver.manage().window().setSize()` to manually set the resolution of the browser you want.

I'm not sure exactly what is in that array you mentioned but I would probably approach your problem in the a different way to you:

**Setting params:**

```
params: {
    resolutionConfig: 'default', //could be default, mobile or tablet
    default: { //set whatever res you need
        resWidth: 1700,
        resHeight: 1500,
        titleLocator: '//div[@title="defaultTitle]"'
    },
    mobile: {
        resWidth: 800,
        resHeight: 1000,
        titleLocator: '//div[@title="mobileTitle]"'
    },
    tablet: {
        resWidth: 1200,
        resHeight: 1200,
        titleLocator: '//div[@title="tabletTitle]"'
    }
},
onPrepare: {
   //See below for explanation
  let requiredHeight = browser.params[browser.params.resolutionConfig].resHeight;
  let requiredWidth = browser.params[browser.params.resolutionConfig].resWidth;
  browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(requiredHeight, requiredWidth)
}
```

You could launch protractor in the same way you are intending

```
protractor conf.js --params.resolutionConfig=Classic
protractor conf.js --params.resolutionConfig=Mobile
protractor conf.js --params.resolutionConfig=Tablet
```

You would locator you dynamic title element like

```
element(by.xpath(browser.params[browser.params.resolutionConfig].titleLocator))
//which is equivalent to 
element(by.xpath(browser.params['default'].titleLocator))
//and as we declared above
browser.params['default'].titleLocator = "//div[@title="defaultTitle]"
//so therefore we are actually doing
element(by.xpath("//div[@title="defaultTitle]"))
```